# How to display items always in the same order when mapping over an array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've created a cart to which items can be added or removed. At some point in my app I'm displaying this cart, which will have max 3 items. However, the order of the items change as I add/remove from the cart.

```
{cartItems.map( item => <p key={`${item.type}-${item.id}`}>{item.name || item.time}</p>)}
```

The items being added have a type property which could be used for setting an order, but I've not been able to use it in my favour.

Two examples of items:

```
{
    "id": "0",
    "type": "service",
    "name": "Painting",
    "isFavorite": false
}

{
    "id": "0",
    "type": "time",
    "day": "today",
    "time": "09:40",
    "isFavorite": false
}
```

how can I always display object with 'time' type before 'service'?

Comment: is `cartItems` part of your component state? Where does it come from?

Comment: The ideal solution is sorting the `cartItems` every time you add or remove from it, so that it's in order and you don't have to worry about it

Comment: the alternative (but not quite as nice) is sorting in your `render` function

Answer (score 0):

```js
const array = [{
    "id": "0",
    "type": "service",
    "name": "Painting",
    "isFavorite": false
  },
  {
    "id": "1",
    "type": "time",
    "day": "today",
    "time": "09:40",
    "isFavorite": false
  }, {
    "id": "2",
    "type": "time",
    "day": "yesterday",
    "time": "09:30",
    "isFavorite": false

  }, {
    "id": "3",
    "type": "service",
    "name": "Some Service",
    "isFavorite": false
  }
];

const sortedArray = array.reduce((acc, object) => {
  const method = 'time' in object ? 'unshift' : 'push';
  acc[method](object);

  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(sortedArray);
```

Comment: An other solution is to use `array.sort((a, b) => (a.type === "time" ? -1 : 1));`

Comment: I cannot change the ids unfortunately

Comment: @kiabbott The above snippet would work correctly with same ids.

Comment: @UmairSarfraz I cannot understand this bit ```acc[method](object);``` care to explain?

Comment: @theblackgigant I'm not able to understand why I would return -1 or 1. Care to explain?

Answer (score 0):

You can write a simple comparison function, which you then use in the array sort.

```
function compare(a, b) {
  if (a.type === b.type) return 0;
  else if (a.type === 'time') return -1;

  return 1;
}

var cartItems = [{
    "id": "0",
    "type": "service",
    "name": "Painting",
    "isFavorite": false
}, {
    "id": "0",
    "type": "time",
    "day": "today",
    "time": "09:40",
    "isFavorite": false
}]

cartItems.sort(compare);
```

And then you can simply call your map on sortedItems as before

```
{cartItems.map( item => <p key={`${item.type}-${item.id}`}>{item.name || item.time}</p>)}
```

Comment: care to explain what the 'return 0' and 'return -1' do in this function? Or point me to some resources so I could understand it?

Comment: @kiabbott of course

```
function compare(a, b) {
  if (a is less than b by some ordering criterion) {
    return -1;
  }
  if (a is greater than b by the ordering criterion) {
    return 1;
  }
  // a must be equal to b
  return 0;
}
```

but even better ... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Comment: I struggle to take this one level further... what if I had another type, say 'business' and I want it to always be at the end of the array. How would I implement that?

Comment: That is then a standard problem of sorting an array with three distinct values, like {0, 1 and 2}s. This was answered multiple times, like here for example https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sort-an-array-of-0s-1s-and-2s/