# How to sort three items in an array in a particular order?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, sorting

This question is an extension from [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59392443/how-to-display-items-always-in-the-same-order-when-mapping-over-an-array/59392600?noredirect=1#comment105018156_59392600)

I've created a cart to which items can be added or removed. At some point in my app I'm displaying this cart, which will have max 3 items. However, the order of the items change as I add/remove from the cart.

```
{cartItems.map( item => <p>{item.name || item.time}</p>)}
```

The items being added have a type property which could be used for setting an order:

```
[{
  "id": "0",
  "type": "service",
  "name": "Painting",
}, {
  "id": "0",
  "type": "time",
  "day": "today",
  "time": "09:40",
}, {
  "id": "0",
  "type": "business",
  "name": "Baron's Motel",
}]
```

So far a kind stranger has taught me how to use sort() for solving this problem with two items

```
function compare(a, b) {
  if (a.type === b.type) return 0;
  else if (a.type === 'time') return -1;
  return 1;
}
```

how can I take this one level further and sort 3 items, always displaying object with 'time' type before 'service', and place 'business' at the end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an object or some other mechanism to store the *weights* of item type:

```js
function compare(a, b) {
   const weights = { time: 0, service: 1, business: 2 };
   return weights[a.type] - weights[b.type];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make an array of the types in the specific order you want. And use the difference of indexes of the the current type inside that array.

```js
const arr = [{
    "id": "0",
    "type": "service",
    "name": "Painting",
},
{
    "id": "0",
    "type": "time",
    "day": "today",
    "time": "09:40",
},
{
    "id": "0",
    "type": "business",
    "name": "Baron's Motel",
}]
let order = ['time', 'service', 'business'];
const res = arr.sort((a, b) => order.indexOf(a.type) - order.indexOf(b.type));

console.log(res)
```